# Event is not emitted

Tags: angular, events, service

Currently I'm using Angular4. Now I have a problem. I have this `HeaderService` to change the title in the `HeaderComponent`:

```
import {EventEmitter, Injectable, Output} from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class HeaderService {

    @Output()
    public fire: EventEmitter<String> = new EventEmitter();

    constructor() {
    }

    public changeTitle(title: string) {
        console.log("Want to change title to: " + title);

        this.fire.emit(title);
    }

    public getTitle(): EventEmitter<String> {
        return this.fire;
    }

}
```

And this is my `HeaderComponent`:

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {HeaderService} from "../../services/header.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'header',
    templateUrl: './header.component.html'
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

    private title: string = "felixoi.net";
    private subscription: EventEmitter<String>;

    constructor(private headerService: HeaderService) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log("Loading HeaderComponent");

        this.subscription = this.headerService.getTitle().subscribe((title: string) => {
            console.log("Changed title to: " + title);

            this.title = title;
        });
    }
}
```

In my `HomeComponent` I use this service to change the title:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {HeaderService} from "../shared/services/header.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private headerService: HeaderService) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log("Loading HomeComponent");

        this.headerService.changeTitle("Home");
    }

}
```

I have the exactly same calls in my `TokenService` but in this component the same code is not working.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {HeaderService} from "../shared/services/header.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'token',
    templateUrl: './token.component.html'
})
export class TokenComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private headerService: HeaderService) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log("Loading TokenComponent");

        this.headerService.changeTitle("Tokens");
    }

}
```

I created some debug messages in my code. This is the console output:

```
Loading HeaderComponent
Loading HomeComponent
Want to change title to: Home
Changed title to: Home
Loading TokenComponent
Want to change title to: Tokens
```

It shows that the event is not emitted on the `TokenComponent` but I don't know why.

Comment: The presented code looks good to me. I'd try to remove the HomeComponent and see if the TokenComponent starts working properly. Creating and posting a plunker with your app would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

The Module was imported multiply times, so different instances existed and also different Emitters to subscribe to.